# prevent git stash from resetting files in .gitignore

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore, git-stash

So I'm using drupal that is version controlled via git

I modified the bootstrap.inc file in drupal that I don't want to push to the origin and should only be in my local environment

I added bootstrap.inc to my ~/.gitignore

however whenever I do a git stash save, my changes in bootstrap.inc gets reset to the head version even though I'm ignoring it...

is there a way to prevent this from happening and still have my own personal changes to bootstrap.inc not being reset by git stash?

Comment: Was the bootstrap.inc file previously tracked in git. I mean before you added it to .gitignore?

Comment: Do you mean you are using git for your own drupal based project, or you are using a git clone of the Drupal project's own git repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you have configuration file that contains some site specific configuration (especially passwords, etc.), it is not very good idea to track such file in any version control system.

Instead, you should try to find a way to keep global config intact, and create site specific overrides. In case of Drupal, it seems like there is a way to do just that with [`conf_path()` function](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/7.x/includes/bootstrap.inc), which will read all site specific info from separate config file.

Answer (score 0):

If the file was already tracked by git, you have to run:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged bootstrap.inc
```

in order for git to ignore any changes to this file on your local environment.

Comment: Yep, `.gitignore` will ignore files that are not tracked. Files that are already tracked behave the normal way.